# How to properly use patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" for svg element?

Tags: svg

I want to apply a pattern to a few svg elements, the pattern should apply from the (0,0) point for each element.

First I try code like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gwrgd1wf/)

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
<defs>
  <pattern id="pattern1"
      x="0" y="0" width="25" height="25"
           patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
    >

      <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" style="stroke: none; fill: #0000ff" />

  </pattern>
</defs>

<rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"
    style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#pattern1);" />  
<rect x="110" y="17" width="100" height="100"
    style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#pattern1);" />
<rect x="210" y="0" width="100" height="100"
    style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#pattern1);" />  
<rect x="0" y="110" width="100" height="100"
    style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#pattern1);" />      
</svg>
```

The issue in this example is that the pattern for each element starts from the (0,0) point of the svg document not of each element.

Ok, lets try (setting the `patternUnits="objectBoundingBox"` attribute to the pattern definition so that the coordinate system for the pattern starts from the (0,0) point of each element)[https://jsfiddle.net/gwrgd1wf/1/]

The Coordinate system start point is changed as I want it, but the pattern has stopped tiling and the `width` and `height` attribute of pattern stop working properly. You can see I set `height="2"`, but it does not change the height of the pattern.

So my question is how to properly use the `patternUnits="objectBoundingBox"` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In objectBoundingBox units 1 unit is the size of the shape so if you write 2 that means the pattern is 2 times the size of the shape so 1/2 the pattern fills the shape and you get no tiling.

If you want tiling you'll need to make the pattern smaller than the shape e.g. with 0.2 you'll get 5 circles displayed. E.g.

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
<defs>
  <pattern id="pattern1" 
      x="0" y="0" width="0.2" height="0.2"
           patternUnits="objectBoundingBox"
    >
      <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" style="stroke: none; fill: #0000ff" />
  </pattern>
</defs>

<rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"
    style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#pattern1);" />  
<rect x="110" y="17" width="100" height="100"
    style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#pattern1);" />
<rect x="210" y="0" width="100" height="100"
    style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#pattern1);" />  
<rect x="0" y="110" width="100" height="100"
    style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#pattern1);" />      
</svg>
```

Comment: If I have a rectangle but not square, is it possible to keep aspect ratio. I.e. set pattern `width`, `height` and `patternUnits="objectBoundingBox"` apply this pattern for different rectangles and not calculate the `width` and `height` attributes of pattern for  each different rectangle?

Comment: Yes, use preserveAspectRatio (note that preserveAspectRatio on patterns doesn't work on Firefox before version 40) If you want more details ask a new question.

Comment: Can you answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31804993/how-to-apply-svg-pattern-to-different-rectangles-using-objectboundingbox-coordin)?