# How to apply svg pattern to different rectangles using objectBoundingBox coordinate system and keep aspect ratio?

Tags: svg

I.e. in this code the pattern applied with gap between the tiles or overlaping.

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
<defs>
  <pattern id="pattern1" 
      x="0" y="0" width="0.1" height="0.2"
      patternUnits="objectBoundingBox"
  >
      <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" style="stroke: none; fill: #0000ff" />
  </pattern>
</defs>

<rect x="10" y="10" width="170" height="100"
    style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#pattern1);" /> 
    
<rect x="10" y="110" width="235" height="100"
    style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#pattern1);" />     
</svg>
```

How to do that tiles were placed side by side and the last tile which is not fit in rectangle will be sliced?

Comment: Something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/YsNcbkG.png)

Comment: If I have a pattern with size (10x10) and a rectangle with width = 103 I want to place the 10 tiles side by side and from the last tile first 3 pixels. And if rectangle has width = 97 then 9 tiles and the first 7 pixels from the last tile. The tile size should be constant for the different rectangles.

Comment: I think you're going to need two separate patterns.

Comment: So what I want is impossible with `objectBoundingBox` option? What if use `userSpaceOnUse` option and when translate the start of pattern coordinate system to the start point of rectangle, but do it not in pattern definition but inside rectangle definition, is it possible?

Comment: Maybe, try it and see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do what you want with `objectBoundingBox` units.  You need to use `patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`.

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
<defs>
  <pattern id="pattern1" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" style="stroke: none; fill: #0000ff" />
  </pattern>
</defs>

<rect x="10" y="10" width="170" height="100"
    style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#pattern1);" /> 
    
<rect x="10" y="110" width="235" height="100"
    style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#pattern1);" />     
</svg>
```

But, as you can see, the default pattern origin is at the origin of the SVG document (the top left).  To change that so that the pattern is aligned with the rectangles, you'll need to define the rectangles at the origin and move them into position with a `transform`.

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
<defs>
  <pattern id="pattern1" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" style="stroke: none; fill: #0000ff" />
  </pattern>
</defs>

<rect x="0" y="0" width="170" height="100" transform="translate(10,10)"
    style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#pattern1);" /> 
    
<rect x="0" y="0" width="235" height="100" transform="translate(10,110)"
    style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#pattern1);" />     
</svg>
```

Comment: Ok, this solution is work, but I think this is hack. For me it would be better if it were possible to place a rectangle at the some point, and when apply a pattern from this point.