# How to set an SVG RECT shape with a background image covering 100% - not tiling

Tags: svg, css-selectors

I'm trying to dynamically have the background of SVG shapes defined as a webpage is rendered server side (sent complete to the browser). Essentially a random SVG will be selected and a random collection of images chose to 'fill' sections. The common thing is I know there will be always 9 needed. i'm wanting 'users' to be able to upload an SVG - so sizes will not be known without parsing the SVG file. The SVG can be inline in the HTML of the site - I had thought this meant I could define the internal SVG shape attributes with CSS.

However after trying several CSS options - none have worked.

I'm currently using Patterns and the referencing them from a style=fill. However the image sizes and SVG rects in each will all be different sizes and positions. I simply can not define a pattern as being 100% wide and have it fill the shape completely.

Here is a basic example of where I am at (a working jsfiddle is below where you can see the 'pattern')

```html
  <svg>
      <defs>
        <pattern id="pattern1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="300" height="200">
         <image x="0" y="0"  width="900" height="600" href="https://media.freestocktextures.com/cache/fb/eb/fbeb11ab97712b303983cd3e22ae8f3a.jpg" />
        </pattern>
      </defs>
      <rect id="block1" x="50" y="50" fill="#cccccc" 
            style="style="fill:url(#pattern1);" " width="100" height="200"/>
    </svg>
```

Ideally I was hoping to use inline CSS such and target the ID's with "background-size:cover" to simply have the images scaled within the rectangle.

I can't seem to do this with patternfill (percentage widths do not work)

Below is a fiddle I have made as a more simplified example.

https://jsfiddle.net/adscjx1L/

Comment: Have you investigated the SVG attribute: preserveAspectRatio? preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" will center an image and size it to the smaller of the height or width (cropping the excess).   preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" and size it to the larger of the height or width (adding blankspace to the smaller dimension).

Comment: you probably want to use objectBoundingBox units so the pattern adapts to the shape.

Comment: @Michael Mullany - thanks I had not see the preserverAspectRatio setting. However adding it to my fiddle I'm not able to get it to work either added to the Pattern or the feImage type.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio

https://jsfiddle.net/adscjx1L/1/

Comment: @RobertLongson I have found suggestions that patternContentUnits are not widely supported so maybe thats why I'm not seeing it (chrome) work
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/patternContentUnits

If anyone has a clear example I would appreciate it.

Comment: patternContentUnits have been [supported for years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31802219/how-to-properly-use-patterncontentunits-objectboundingbox-for-svg-element) in Chrome and other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be over-engineering this. Just use the image element directly with a preserveAspectRatio. No need for patterns or filters.

```css
body{
  background-color: #eee;
}

#mask,#frame{
  box-shadow: 0px -2px 14px #0000007d;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="500.46px" viewBox="0 0 283.46 283.46">

        <path id="frame" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M141.284,20.828c-17.516,0-34.33,5.309-48.625,15.354C81.489,44.031,72.49,54.305,66.25,66.249
            c-11.944,6.24-22.218,15.239-30.066,26.409C26.14,106.953,20.83,123.767,20.83,141.282c0,17.517,5.31,34.33,15.354,48.623
            c7.849,11.171,18.123,20.169,30.067,26.411c6.24,11.942,15.239,22.218,26.409,30.064c14.295,10.045,31.109,15.354,48.625,15.354
            c17.518,0,34.332-5.31,48.625-15.354c11.169-7.847,20.168-18.122,26.41-30.064c11.941-6.242,22.216-15.24,30.065-26.409
            c10.042-14.295,15.352-31.108,15.352-48.625c0-17.516-5.309-34.33-15.352-48.623c-7.85-11.169-18.121-20.167-30.064-26.408
            c-6.241-11.944-15.239-22.219-26.41-30.068C175.616,26.138,158.802,20.828,141.284,20.828L141.284,20.828z"/>

    <defs>
  
        <path id="Mask" d="M238.746,141.282c0-26.354-16.534-48.835-39.789-57.669c-8.833-23.258-31.315-39.794-57.673-39.794
            c-26.355,0-48.839,16.534-57.672,39.791c-23.257,8.834-39.792,31.317-39.792,57.672c0,26.356,16.534,48.837,39.791,57.672
            c8.834,23.257,31.318,39.791,57.673,39.791s48.838-16.534,57.672-39.791C222.212,190.119,238.746,167.638,238.746,141.282z"/>
    </defs>
  
    <clipPath id="Mask_1_">
        <use xlink:href="#Mask"  overflow="visible"/>
    </clipPath>
  
    <g clip-path="url(#Mask_1_)">
        <image id="block1" x="43.82" y="43.819" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"  xlink:href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1629268810152-b99c4f0ef937?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80);" width="97.463" height="97.463"/>
        <image id="block2" x="141.283" y="43.819" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" xlink:href="https://media.freestocktextures.com/cache/c3/d5/c3d5afbfcadee27d1452eec759ba8c26.jpg" width="97.463" height="97.463"/>
        <image id="block3" x="43.82" y="141.281" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"  xlink:href="https://media.freestocktextures.com/cache/c3/d5/c3d5afbfcadee27d1452eec759ba8c26.jpg" width="97.463" height="97.464"/>
        <image id="block4" x="141.283" y="141.281"  width="97.463" height="97.464" xlink:href="https://media.freestocktextures.com/cache/fb/eb/fbeb11ab97712b303983cd3e22ae8f3a.jpg"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
    />
    
        <image id="block5" x="105.207" y="105.207" width="72.151" height="92.151" href="https://media.freestocktextures.com/cache/c3/d5/c3d5afbfcadee27d1452eec759ba8c26.jpg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"/>
    </g>

</svg>
```